# cellForRowAtIndexPath how to skip a row for data generated through PFQueryTableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to skip a row creation in my cellForRowAtIndexPath without empty cells in between while retrieving data from PFQueryTableViewController ? How can i create a cell when my condition satisfies and skip creating a blank cell ?

Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {


    //NSLog(@"data is %@",[object objectForKey:@"ItemName"]);

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"userData"];

    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * userData, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
//Doing some logic to get result
 if  (result == a) {

                static NSString *CellIdentifier  = @"ident";
                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

                if(cell == nil){
                    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                }


                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"ItemName"];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Price"];
                cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                [_itemPrefArray removeAllObjects];
                [_userPrefArray removeAllObjects];

            return cell;
            }

        }else {
            NSLog(@"Error: error setting cell data %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
```

It is throwing compilation error as i am not aware of how to return a cell based on condition. I tried using `id cell = nil;` and tried returning which is not working.

Comment: If I were you, I would query outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath: and upon successful completion, than call tableView.reloadData() and use the date you queried for to fill the contents of the cell

Comment: Hi Josh thanks for your reply. This works if i have less number of rows but i want to leverage the methods of PFQTVC and dynamically do comparisons based on the data that i query inside cellforRowIndexPath.

Comment: to me, it seems every time you want a cell, you're performing the same query. In reality, you only need to do this query once and store the data in an array of some sorts. when the query is finished, call tableView.reloadData() and then when cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called, index the array that contains the results of your query and fill in the corresponding data in your text fields. Do you need an example?

Comment: I understood your approach. Are you telling me to get rid of PFQTVC ? Yes Example will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: may i ask what you're trying to do for this table view ? Since you're only getting the first object, every cell is related to the same piece of data. Also, what's object referring to in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: I am trying to compare userData attributes with attributes that i am getting from - (PFQuery *)queryForTable { PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className]; } and everytime cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called each row from this query is populated and i am comparing both.

Comment: okay, how do you know how many cells to make?

Comment: Currently i am making a cell for all rows of data from - (PFQuery *)queryForTable { ... however i should only create a cell if my condition inside cellForRowAtIndexPath  if(result == a) satisfies.

Comment: okay is there another query you're referring to? Because the one you have above returns only one result so that would correspond to only one row. Sorry for asking so many questions, i want to give you a good example to refer to

Comment: Not a problem. Yes the other query is inside (PFQuery *)queryForTable {  and that populates inside cellForRowAtIndexPath through (PFObject *)object. So for every row of data that i get through queryForTable i will compare with the query inside cellForRowAtIndexPath and i will compare both results.

Answer (score 0):

So based on what I understand, you should query for the user data only once, most likely in viewWillLoad(), if that scenario fits. Once the query is successful, use the results of the query to filter your other query to determine which objects meet your predicate requirements and save those objects that fit your predicate to an NSMutableArray. This array corresponds to all the records that match what you're trying to do. This array corresponds to the number of cells in the tableview and then in cellForRowAtIndexPath: , to get the contents of the cell, just index the results array based on indexPath.row.

I tried to provide a trivial example to show you what I'm thinking of since I cannot provide any more specifics without knowing the other queries and the predicate you're using to find matches..

```
-(void)queryForUserData(){
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"userData"];

    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * userData, NSError *error) {
         if(error == nil){
             filterResultsUsingUserData(userData);
             tableView.reloadData();
         }
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
                     static NSString *CellIdentifier  = @"ident";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if(cell == nil){
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            //Use the results from filterResultsUsingUserData to fill in contents
}


-(void)filterResultsUsingUserData(PFObject*)userData{
      //Filter results based on a predicate you're comparing to and save to immutable property. Number of results corresponds to number of cells
      for(int i = 0;i < objects.count;i++){
           if(a == b){
               results.addObject(objects[i]);
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh! I will try to implement according to my scenario and will get back soon.

Comment: Josh I modified my filterResultsUsingUserData in my previous screen and passed those values to this screen. And i did the PFQuery *query inside viewDidLoad and after processing the results i stored everything in an NSArray and did [self.tableView reloadData];. In short i removed PFQTVC and now everything is working as expected. Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction.

Comment: I think you cannot do two background tasks and then i tried doing PFQTVC which hampered me from building sections.

Comment: awesome!! I'm guessing there's a limit on the number of background tasks you can run at once and you were exceeding that previously